# Hibernate Search cluster and near-real-time search

Tags: java, lucene, search-engine, hibernate-search

I'm trying to find the best indexing solution for implementing a search-engine in my clustered webapp, and I cannot find a clear answer to my questions in official documentations.

My Java/Java EE backend will be deployed among several load-balanced instances. The search-engine will require near-real-time availability of indexed data (i.e. less than 5 seconds between the indexation and the retrievability).

Hibernate Search can work in a clustered environment with [JGroups](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.2/reference/en/html/search-configuration.html#jgroups-backend) but the documentation also says, about near-real-time that [as a tradeoff it requires a non-clustered and non-shared index](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e841).

- Does that mean that *NRTIndexManager* cannot be used in a JGroups Slave/Master setup ? i.e. can only be used whith one single node ?
- Does that mean that with such a setup, the availability of indexed data depends only on the refresh period (period of index copy to slave nodes) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the standard IndexManager, you only see the latest changes when they are written to the disk and you reopen your IndexSearcher.

By default, Hibernate Search writes to disk and opens a new IndexSearcher for each query so you're sure your searches are always in sync with your database.

The NRTIndexManager is different from the standard one because it allows you to search on the latest changes indexed without an explicit write on disk. It's typically used when you need a high throughput and you can't write everything on the disk right away. So it's not really correlated to the fact that you will see your changes right away or not: it's an optimization when you can allow some index data loss - the latest changes might be lost.

As mentioned in the documentation here http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.5/reference/en-US/html_single/#jgroups-backend , you can have a sync JGroups with Hibernate Search blocking until all the indexes are in sync. So it can work for your case.

Note that we are currently working for 5.6 on an Elasticsearch backend which might be of some interest to you as it's typically designed for your case. It's still in beta but it's already in pretty good shape. You might want to take a look to it: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.6/reference/en-US/html/ch11.html .

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I may be missing a point.From what I understand, using JGroups (or JMS) in a clustered environment allow your index to be copied on several nodes. All index updates are delegated to master node, and the master index is then copied to slave nodes every X seconds. Since search requests are processed on local indexes, the freshness of retrievable data depends on the period configured. I understand that NRTIndexManager is not meant to satisfy my needs here, but is there a way to make changes to master index replicated to slave nodes indexes in a few seconds ?

Comment: It highly depends on the size of your index. If the size of your index is consequent and you can't copy it to the slaves every X seconds, it won't work properly for you. My advice: try the Elasticsearch backend of Hibernate Search 5.6.0.Beta1, it's your best bet to have something up and running with your constraints if your index is large. We would really like to have more feedback on it!

Comment: Ok I may will give it a shot. What would be the advantage of using this against pure ElasticSearch ? Besides not having to manually write index creation/update routines. Btw my index files will be quite small (20Mb top), but to copy the full index every X seconds seems overkill compared to ElasticSearch way of splitting data among nodes.

Comment: You get all the goodies of Hibernate Search: you manipulate managed entities, you don't have to manage your index manually, the schema is automatically generated from your annotations, you get the FieldBridge magic and so on. It's as if you asked me what Hibernate Search brings you compared to using Lucene directly ;).